# Static variables in Scheme/Racket?

Tags: static, scheme, racket, continuations

In C, you can have a static variable within a method, which can remember values to which it was set by previous calls of the method. I heard that the same effect can be found by using continuations within Scheme. Can anyone show me how to create the similar effect of a static variable for a function in Scheme without using mutation?

Comment: You say "without mutation", which is a bit strange since you're comparing to C. Are you trying to model mutation using continuations? You can do this, but the result is going to be something that's essentially mutation by another name. Eli's solution is definitely the "sane" one here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need continuations for that.  Here's a classic example:

```
(define counter
  (let ([n 0])
    (lambda ()
      (set! n (add1 n))
      n)))
(list (counter) (counter) (counter))
```

And here's an obvious generalization to make it more interesting:

```
(define (make-counter n)
  (lambda ()
    (set! n (add1 n))
    n))
(define a (make-counter 0))
(define b (make-counter 10))
(list (a) (a) (a) (b) (b) (a) (a))
```

And here's the first piece of code translated to JS:

```
var counter = (function() {
                 var n = 0;
                 return (function() {
                           n++;
                           return n;
                         });
               })();
```

Comment: OMG! Counters! It's like everybody's favourite dog-and-pony show of closures-for-state. :-) (Including mine. I'm going to nuke my dupe answer now.)

Comment: Yeah, I did refer to it as a "classic".  Pretty obvious when you think about it -- adding 1 is pretty much the first thing you try when you're testing stateness...

Answer (score 1):

You can close values in Scheme (or any language with a decent `lambda` construct), so [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) give you a good way to have "static variables".

(and if you want to mutate these closed values, you could put them in a container)

Answer (score 0):

for example, if we want to set a static variable named 'a' in a function named 'f', then we can write like this:

```
(define f
  (let ((a 5))
    (lambda (m) 
      (if (> m 7)
          (set! a (- a 1))
          (set! a (+ a m)))
      a)))
(f 1)
(f 2)
```

Comment: 0
down vote
I know this must be a really dumb question, but where does the value of counter's internal "n" live when counter is not running? Why is it not reset to 0 the next time counter runs? If n were a global variable I would understand...